# delete particular word in power point using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to delete some word in power point using python irrespective of uppercase/lowercase

```
import re
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation(r'C:\Users\......\xxx.pptx')


for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            if(shape.text.find("sign"))!=-1:
                text_frame = shape.text_frame
                cur_text = text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text
                new_text = cur_text.replace(str("sign"), str(""))
                text_frame.paragraphs[0].runs[0].text = new_text
prs.save(r'C:\Users\....\xxx.pptx')
```

In this code, i am trying to delete all word "sign" present in power point.
Also i want to delete all word like "SIgn", "sigN" "SiGn" but not "zzsignzz", "xxSigN", "SiGnxx".

Can anyone take a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to replace unwanted text.

- Use a pattern to optimize search and replacement, as you will be always looking for the same word
- Use `IGNORECASE` flag to catch all your `sign` possibilities
- Put `\b` before and after your pattern to mark your word boundaries (this way `xxsign` will be ignored)

As example:

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\bsign\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
>>> words = ["SIgn", "sigN" "SiGn", "zzsignzz", "xxSigN", "SiGnxx"]
>>> for word in words:
>>>   new_word = pattern.sub("", word)
>>>   print(new_word)
''
''
''
'sigNSiGn'
'zzsignzz'
'xxSigN'
'SiGnxx'
```

I'm not expert about `pptx` library, but you could try:

```py
import re
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation(r'C:\Users\......\xxx.pptx')

pattern = re.compile(r"\bsign\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            shape.text_frame = pattern.sub("", shape.text_frame)

prs.save(r'C:\Users\....\xxx.pptx')
```